# Function accumulated

Tags: r

```
a <- function(x){
         a = 2*x*x
         return(a)
         }
 b (x) <- a(1) + a(2) + ... + a(x)
```

there is function a, I want to write a function b,which is a accumulation of function a.
I write it in R.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
a <- function(x)
{2*x*x}

b<- function(y)
{sum(sapply(seq(y),a))}
```

so

```
b(3) = 28
```

since

```
b(3) = a(1) + a(2) + a(3) 
     = 2*1*1 + 2*2*2 + 2*3*3 
     = 2 + 8 + 18 
     = 28
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `b` creates an expression and evaluates that expression to return the result.

```
a <- function(x){
  return(2*x*x)
}  

b <- function(x){
  eval( parse( text = paste0( strsplit( paste0( "a(", x, ")"), " "), collapse = "+") ))
} 

b(1:2)
# [1] 10
b(1:3)
# [1] 28
b(1:5)
# [1] 110
b(c(2,4,6))
# [1] 112
```